# Face Recognition in Video using OpenCV gives unhandled exception

Tags: opencv, face-recognition, unhandled-exception

I am trying to use the Face Recognition in video sample provided with OpenCV. The only modification I've done is: Instead of using command line arguments to provide CSV and Cascade classifier paths, I have given them directly in the code. This is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

static void read_csv(const string& filename, vector<Mat>& images, vector<int>& labels, char separator = ';') {
    std::ifstream file(filename.c_str(), ifstream::in);
    if (!file) {
        string error_message = "No valid input file was given, please check the given filename.";
        CV_Error(CV_StsBadArg, error_message);
    }
    string line, path, classlabel;
    while (getline(file, line)) {
        stringstream liness(line);
        getline(liness, path, separator);
        getline(liness, classlabel);
        if(!path.empty() && !classlabel.empty()) {
            images.push_back(imread(path, 0));
            labels.push_back(atoi(classlabel.c_str()));
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
// Check for valid command line arguments, print usage
// if no arguments were given.
if (argc != 4) {
    cout << "usage: " << argv[0] << " </path/to/haar_cascade> </path/to/csv.ext> </path/to/device id>" << endl;
    cout << "\t </path/to/haar_cascade> -- Path to the Haar Cascade for face detection." << endl;
    cout << "\t </path/to/csv.ext> -- Path to the CSV file with the face database." << endl;
    cout << "\t <device id> -- The webcam device id to grab frames from." << endl;
    //exit(1);
}
// Get the path to your CSV:
string fn_haar = "C:\\OpenCV-2.4.2\\opencv\\data\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml";
string fn_csv = "C:\\Users\\gaspl\\Desktop\\train.txt";
int deviceId = 1;
// These vectors hold the images and corresponding labels:
vector<Mat> images;
vector<int> labels;
// Read in the data (fails if no valid input filename is given, but you'll get an error message):
try {
    read_csv(fn_csv, images, labels);
} catch (cv::Exception& e) {
    cerr << "Error opening file \"" << fn_csv << "\". Reason: " << e.msg << endl;
    // nothing more we can do
    exit(1);
}
// Get the height from the first image. We'll need this
// later in code to reshape the images to their original
// size AND we need to reshape incoming faces to this size:
int im_width = images[0].cols;
int im_height = images[0].rows;
// Create a FaceRecognizer and train it on the given images:
Ptr<FaceRecognizer> model = createFisherFaceRecognizer();
model->train(images, labels);
// That's it for learning the Face Recognition model. You now
// need to create the classifier for the task of Face Detection.
// We are going to use the haar cascade you have specified in the
// command line arguments:
//
CascadeClassifier haar_cascade;
haar_cascade.load(fn_haar);
// Get a handle to the Video device:
VideoCapture cap(deviceId);
// Check if we can use this device at all:
if(!cap.isOpened()) {
    cerr << "Capture Device ID " << deviceId << "cannot be opened." << endl;
    return -1;
}
// Holds the current frame from the Video device:
Mat frame;
for(;;) {
    cap >> frame;
    // Clone the current frame:
    Mat original = frame.clone();
    // Convert the current frame to grayscale:
    Mat gray;
    cvtColor(original, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    // Find the faces in the frame:
    vector< Rect_<int> > faces;
    haar_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, faces);
    // At this point you have the position of the faces in
    // faces. Now we'll get the faces, make a prediction and
    // annotate it in the video. Cool or what?
    for(int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++) {
        // Process face by face:
        Rect face_i = faces[i];
        // Crop the face from the image. So simple with OpenCV C++:
        Mat face = gray(face_i);
        // Resizing the face is necessary for Eigenfaces and Fisherfaces. You can easily
        // verify this, by reading through the face recognition tutorial coming with OpenCV.
        // Resizing IS NOT NEEDED for Local Binary Patterns Histograms, so preparing the
        // input data really depends on the algorithm used.
        //
        // I strongly encourage you to play around with the algorithms. See which work best
        // in your scenario, LBPH should always be a contender for robust face recognition.
        //
        // Since I am showing the Fisherfaces algorithm here, I also show how to resize the
        // face you have just found:
        Mat face_resized;
        cv::resize(face, face_resized, Size(im_width, im_height), 1.0, 1.0, INTER_CUBIC);
        // Now perform the prediction, see how easy that is:
        int prediction = model->predict(face_resized);
        // And finally write all we've found out to the original image!
        // First of all draw a green rectangle around the detected face:
        rectangle(original, face_i, CV_RGB(0, 255,0), 1);
        // Create the text we will annotate the box with:
        string box_text = format("Prediction = %d", prediction);
        // Calculate the position for annotated text (make sure we don't
        // put illegal values in there):
        int pos_x = std::max(face_i.tl().x - 10, 0);
        int pos_y = std::max(face_i.tl().y - 10, 0);
        // And now put it into the image:
        putText(original, box_text, Point(pos_x, pos_y), FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1.0, CV_RGB(0,255,0), 2.0);
    }
    // Show the result:
    imshow("face_recognizer", original);
    // And display it:
    char key = (char) waitKey(20);
    // Exit this loop on escape:
    if(key == 27)
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is what my `train.txt` CSV file looks like:

```
C:\\Training\\extract0.jpg;0
C:\\Training\\extract1.jpg;0
C:\\Training\\extract2.jpg;0
```

However when I try to run the sample (it builds fine), I get these errors and it asks me to `Break`:

```
First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFE04CAED in facrec.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x000000000025C530.
Unhandled exception at at 0x000007FEFE04CAED in facrec.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x000000000025C530.
```

The error occurs at the point where I initialize the Fisher Recognizer:

```
Ptr<FaceRecognizer> model = createFisherFaceRecognizer();
model->train(images, labels);
```

I am using Windows 7 64-bit with Visual Studio 2012 and OpenCV 2.4.2 (Build Configuration: x64-Release)

I have already tried face detection and face extraction and they work fine on my computer([If anyone wants to check out the code](https://github.com/karanjthakkar)), so there is apparently no problem with my Visual studio project settings (Linker or C/C++).

[There is a similar question here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/938/unhandled-exception-facerecognizer-vs2010-windows/) but it still doesnt solve anything.

Anything wrong with what I am doing?

Comment: Exception usually says what goes wrong. You should handle it and look to its message.

Comment: @AndreyKamaev I've tried to debug it, and it seems that the problem is with this line in the code `images.push_back(imread(path, 0));` within the `read_csv()` funtion. It does not add image data in the `images` array, which is why the Fisher training and prediction functions give an exception. Is there something wrong with the `imread()` implementation or with the path format in the CSV file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As we have already concluded by mail. This happens, because only one label is given in your CSV file:

```
C:\Training\extract0.jpg;0
C:\Training\extract1.jpg;0
C:\Training\extract2.jpg;0
```

The Fisherfaces method needs at least two classes to learn a model. This case should have been caught and OpenCV 2.4.2 throws the following exception on my system:

```
OpenCV Error: Bad argument (At least two classes are needed to perform a LDA. Reason: Only one class was given!) in lda, file /home/philipp/github/libfacerec/src/subspace.cpp, line 150
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/philipp/github/libfacerec/src/subspace.cpp:150: error: (-5) At least two classes are needed to perform a LDA. Reason: Only one class was given! in function lda
```

Which makes the error in the training data quite clear. I don't know, why this exception isn't thrown on your Windows 7 installation, but I'll set up a test system to reproduce as soon as possible and fix accordingly.

Comment: Any alternative when I only have one label?